Regret bound of returned policies
I encountered a proof in the paper Imitation Projected Programmatic Reinforcement Learning that I find puzzling.
In particular, it is Theorem A.2 in the appendix, in the section of Bounding relative improvement. I cannot figure out how they went from equation (14) to equation (15). They did not explain how they arrived there.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
